# Pulp optimisation debugging

Tags: python, pulp

It's the first time I am using pulp, and I am playing around with a simple problem to see how it works. Basically I downloaded a stock price curve and I am trying to optimise when to sell and buy based on prices over an horizon, with a stock variable. I do not understand what is going wrong here, nor how I can show more precisely what is the error. I am getting the following error message:

```
An error occurred during optimization:
dyld[657]: Library not loaded: '@rpath/liblapack.3.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Users/pepeslier/anaconda3/lib/libCoinUtils.3.11.6.dylib'
  Reason: tried: '/Users/XXX/anaconda3/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/XXX/anaconda3/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/XXX/anaconda3/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/XXX/anaconda3/bin/../lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/XXX/anaconda3/bin/../lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/liblapack.3.dylib' (no such file)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/XXX/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 37, in <module>
    model.solve()
  File "/Users/XXX/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pulp/pulp.py", line 1913, in solve
    status = solver.actualSolve(self, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/XXX/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pulp/apis/coin_api.py", line 137, in actualSolve
    return self.solve_CBC(lp, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/XXX/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pulp/apis/coin_api.py", line 206, in solve_CBC
    raise PulpSolverError(
pulp.apis.core.PulpSolverError: Pulp: Error while trying to execute, use msg=True for more detailscbc
```

Anyone able to help? Also are there any best practice for structure of the code to follow?

```
import pulp
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import yfinance as yf
import traceback

df = yf.download(tickers='AAL.L', start='2018-01-01',end='2018-02-01')
   
try:
    # Create a PuLP problem
    model = pulp.LpProblem("Profits", pulp.LpMaximize)
    
    #Define parameters
    T = len(df['Close'])

    price = df['Close'].values
 
    # Define decision variables 
    Buy  = {t: pulp.LpVariable(f"Buy_{t}" , lowBound=0) for t in range(T)}
    Sell = {t: pulp.LpVariable(f"Sell_{t}", lowBound=0) for t in range(T)}
    SOC  = {t: pulp.LpVariable(f"SOC_{t}" , lowBound=0) for t in range(T)}

    # Define constraints
    model += SOC[0] == 10
    model += Buy[0] <= SOC[0]
    model += Sell[0] == 0
    
    for t in range(1,T):
        model += SOC[t] == SOC[t-1] - Buy[t]/price[t] + Sell[t]*price[t]
        model += Buy[t] <= SOC[t] 
        model += Sell[t] <= SOC[t]
     
    # Define the objective function
    model += pulp.lpSum( Sell[t] * price[t] - Buy[t] * price[t] for t in range(T) )
   
    model.solve()

    # Check if the solution is optimal
    if pulp.LpStatus[model.status] == "Optimal":
        # Print the variable values and other results
        for var in model.variables():
            print(f"{var.name}: {var.varValue}")
        print("Objective value:", pulp.value(model.objective))
    else:
        print("Optimal solution not found.")

except pulp.PulpSolverError:
    print("An error occurred during optimization:")
    print(traceback.format_exc())
except Exception:
    print("An unexpected error occurred:")
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Comment: please `import traceback` and in each of your exceptions use `print(traceback.format_exc())` instead of `print(e)`, then post that

Comment: just added to the question.

Comment: code posted has a few syntax errors.  Try fixing the imports or use consistent naming.  Either `from pulp import *` or do full naming in the code.  Try running it outside of notebook (your debug shows `ipykernel`).  Also, if you just installed `pulp`, log out/log in to make sure the solver that `pulp` installs (cbc) is properly registered.  You should be getting a "problem is unbounded" result from the solver

Comment: Edit your post with above fixes if you are still stuck after trying that stuff.

Comment: `from pulp import *` is an anti-solution..

Comment: It's legal.  It's also a bad practice.  But my point was there are syntax errors now as some of the imported functions are not prefixed

Comment: @AirSquid I am still having problem, but it would seem that it is with some packages that are not recognized although installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original problem contains **unbounded variables**.

An unbounded variable can take on infinitely large (or small) values without breaking any of the rules (constraints) you've set for a problem. In other words, it's a variable that was not properly constrained.

The core problem with the model leading to it being unbounded can be identified by understanding the constraints and the objective function:

1. **Decision Variables**:

   - `Buy`: This represents the amount you're **spending to buy the stock on a given day.**
   - `Sell`: This represents the value you're **receiving by selling the stock on a given day.**
   - `SOC`: State of Charge, the **balance or available funds.** It starts with a value of 10.
2. **Objective Function**:

   - The objective is to maximize the difference between the money received by selling and the money spent buying over the entire period `T`.
3. **Constraints**:

   - **The initial conditions:** `SOC[0]` is 10, `Buy[0]` can't exceed this amount, and you're not selling on the first day.
   - The state of charge on any day `t` is determined by the previous day's balance (`SOC[t-1]`), the money you spent buying, and the money you received selling on that day.

Here's the problem:

When you set the equation `SOC[t] = SOC[t-1] - Buy[t]/price[t] + Sell[t]*price[t]`, this indicates that you are buying stocks in fractions of their value (i.e., `Buy[t]/price[t]` gives you the fraction/quantity of stock you buy) and selling them for their actual value.

Given the objective function is to maximize profits, the optimization will always strive to buy as much as possible (or at least a significant fraction) on the days when the stock price is lowest and sell as much as possible (or at least a significant fraction) on the days when the stock price is highest.

Because you aren't limiting the maximum number of stocks you can hold or how much you can buy/sell, the solver finds the solution by buying an infinite amount of stock on the cheapest days and selling an infinite amount on the most expensive days, thus the solution is unbounded.

To fix this you need to:

1. **Limit the Quantity of Stocks**: Introduce a constraint to limit the maximum number of stocks you can hold at any point.
2. **Consistency in Units**: Make sure you are consistent with the units. If `Buy` and `Sell` represent money, then the SOC should represent the balance in terms of money, and you'll need another variable (or set of variables) to represent the number of stocks you hold.

Here's a modified version of your problem, with the necessary corrections:

```py
# == Necessary Imports =========================================================
import pulp
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf


# == Stock Price Data ==========================================================
df = yf.download(tickers='AAL.L', start='2018-01-01',end='2018-02-01')

# == Define the Problem Instance ===============================================
model = pulp.LpProblem("Profits", pulp.LpMaximize)

# == Define the model parameters ===============================================
INITIAL_SOC = 10_000
price = df['Close'].values
T = len(price)

# == Define the decision variables =============================================
# Variables groups definitions:
# - Buy_money: Amount of money spent buying stock on day t
# - Buy_stock: Number of stocks bought on day t
# - Sell_money: Amount of money obtained by selling stocks on day t
# - Sell_stock: Number of stocks sold on day t
# - SOC_money: Money available on day t
# - SOC_stock: Stocks in possession on day t

Buy_money = {t: pulp.LpVariable(f"Buy_money_{t:02d}", lowBound=0) for t in range(T)}
Buy_stock = {t: pulp.LpVariable(f"Buy_stock_{t:02d}", lowBound=0) for t in range(T)}

Sell_money = {t: pulp.LpVariable(f"Sell_money_{t:02d}", lowBound=0) for t in range(T)}
Sell_stock = {t: pulp.LpVariable(f"Sell_stock_{t:02d}", lowBound=0) for t in range(T)}

SOC_money = {t: pulp.LpVariable(f"SOC_money_{t:02d}", lowBound=0) for t in range(T)}
SOC_stock = {t: pulp.LpVariable(f"SOC_stock_{t:02d}", lowBound=0) for t in range(T)}

# == Constraints ===============================================================
# Initial constraints (day 0)
model += SOC_money[0] == INITIAL_SOC
model += SOC_stock[0] == 0

model += Sell_stock[0] == 0
model += Sell_money[0] == Sell_stock[0] * price[0]

model += Buy_money[0] <= SOC_money[0]
model += Buy_money[0] == Buy_stock[0] * price[0]

# Daily constraints (from day 1 to T)
for t in range(1, T):
    model += SOC_money[t] == SOC_money[t-1] - Buy_money[t] + Sell_stock[t] * price[t]
    model += SOC_stock[t] == SOC_stock[t-1] + Buy_money[t] * price[t]**-1 - Sell_stock[t]
    model += Buy_money[t] <= SOC_money[t]
    model += Sell_stock[t] <= SOC_stock[t]
    model += Buy_stock[t] == Buy_money[t] * price[t]**-1
    model += Sell_money[t] == Sell_stock[t] * price[t]

# == Define the objective function =============================================
# Objective: maximize the amount of money available on day T
model.setObjective(SOC_money[T-1])

# == Solve the Problem =========================================================
print(pulp.LpStatus[model.solve()])

# == Model Results =============================================================
res = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Buy_money": [v.value() for v in Buy_money.values()],
        "Buy_stock": [v.value() for v in Buy_stock.values()],
        "Sell_money": [v.value() for v in Sell_money.values()],
        "Sell_stock": [v.value() for v in Sell_stock.values()],
        "SOC_money": [v.value() for v in SOC_money.values()],
        "SOC_stock": [v.value() for v in SOC_stock.values()],
        "Price": price,
    }
)

# Check if the solution is optimal
if model.status == 1:
    # Print the variable and objective values
    print(f"Objective value: {model.objective.value():.2f}")
    for var in sorted(model.variables(), key=lambda value: value.name):
        print(f"{var.name}: {var.value():.2f}")
else:
    print(f"Optimal solution not found. Status: {pulp.LpStatus[model.status]!r}")
```

The above code returns the following solution:

```
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.3 
Build Date: Dec 15 2019 

command line - /opt/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pulp/solverdir/cbc/osx/64/cbc /var/folders/t5/5_nvwwz94jq9nfwy6zv8s3_40000gn/T/6b63fec594f44667b877067dc8ac13d5-pulp.mps max timeMode elapsed branch printingOptions all solution /var/folders/t5/5_nvwwz94jq9nfwy6zv8s3_40000gn/T/6b63fec594f44667b877067dc8ac13d5-pulp.sol (default strategy 1)
At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 137 COLUMNS
At line 484 RHS
At line 617 BOUNDS
At line 618 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 132 rows, 132 columns and 345 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
Option for timeMode changed from cpu to elapsed
Presolve 58 (-74) rows, 59 (-73) columns and 216 (-129) elements
Perturbing problem by 0.001% of 3.5817644 - largest nonzero change 0.00062727687 ( 0.022655903%) - largest zero change 0.000204439
0  Obj -0 Primal inf 633.58663 (1) Dual inf 13.512595 (4)
0  Obj -0 Primal inf 633.58663 (1) Dual inf 1.4861974e+10 (7)
31  Obj 10499.681 Dual inf 0.86288538 (12)
43  Obj 11070.748
Optimal - objective value 11070.748
After Postsolve, objective 11070.748, infeasibilities - dual 0 (0), primal 0 (0)
Optimal objective 11070.74773 - 43 iterations time 0.002, Presolve 0.00
Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

Optimal
Objective value: 11070.75
Buy_money_00: 0.00
Buy_money_01: 5000.00
Buy_money_02: 2500.00
Buy_money_03: 1250.00
Buy_money_04: 625.00
Buy_money_05: 312.50
Buy_money_06: 156.25
Buy_money_07: 78.12
Buy_money_08: 39.06
Buy_money_09: 0.00
Buy_money_10: 2795.80
Buy_money_11: 1397.90
Buy_money_12: 0.00
Buy_money_13: 0.00
Buy_money_14: 0.00
Buy_money_15: 0.00
Buy_money_16: 0.00
Buy_money_17: 0.00
Buy_money_18: 0.00
Buy_money_19: 0.00
Buy_money_20: 0.00
Buy_money_21: 0.00
Buy_stock_00: 0.00
Buy_stock_01: 3.17
Buy_stock_02: 1.56
Buy_stock_03: 0.78
Buy_stock_04: 0.39
Buy_stock_05: 0.19
Buy_stock_06: 0.09
Buy_stock_07: 0.04
Buy_stock_08: 0.02
Buy_stock_09: 0.00
Buy_stock_10: 1.60
Buy_stock_11: 0.80
Buy_stock_12: 0.00
Buy_stock_13: 0.00
Buy_stock_14: 0.00
Buy_stock_15: 0.00
Buy_stock_16: 0.00
Buy_stock_17: 0.00
Buy_stock_18: 0.00
Buy_stock_19: 0.00
Buy_stock_20: 0.00
Buy_stock_21: 0.00
SOC_money_00: 10000.00
SOC_money_01: 5000.00
SOC_money_02: 2500.00
SOC_money_03: 1250.00
SOC_money_04: 625.00
SOC_money_05: 312.50
SOC_money_06: 156.25
SOC_money_07: 78.12
SOC_money_08: 39.06
SOC_money_09: 5591.60
SOC_money_10: 2795.80
SOC_money_11: 1397.90
SOC_money_12: 6242.30
SOC_money_13: 8657.90
SOC_money_14: 9890.60
SOC_money_15: 10483.15
SOC_money_16: 10781.79
SOC_money_17: 10930.81
SOC_money_18: 11005.38
SOC_money_19: 11043.12
SOC_money_20: 11061.57
SOC_money_21: 11070.75
SOC_stock_00: 0.00
SOC_stock_01: 3.17
SOC_stock_02: 4.74
SOC_stock_03: 5.52
SOC_stock_04: 5.91
SOC_stock_05: 6.10
SOC_stock_06: 6.19
SOC_stock_07: 6.23
SOC_stock_08: 6.26
SOC_stock_09: 3.13
SOC_stock_10: 4.73
SOC_stock_11: 5.53
SOC_stock_12: 2.76
SOC_stock_13: 1.38
SOC_stock_14: 0.69
SOC_stock_15: 0.35
SOC_stock_16: 0.17
SOC_stock_17: 0.09
SOC_stock_18: 0.04
SOC_stock_19: 0.02
SOC_stock_20: 0.01
SOC_stock_21: 0.01
Sell_money_00: 0.00
Sell_money_01: 0.00
Sell_money_02: 0.00
Sell_money_03: 0.00
Sell_money_04: 0.00
Sell_money_05: 0.00
Sell_money_06: 0.00
Sell_money_07: 0.00
Sell_money_08: 0.00
Sell_money_09: 5552.54
Sell_money_10: 0.00
Sell_money_11: 0.00
Sell_money_12: 4844.40
Sell_money_13: 2415.60
Sell_money_14: 1232.70
Sell_money_15: 592.55
Sell_money_16: 298.65
Sell_money_17: 149.01
Sell_money_18: 74.57
Sell_money_19: 37.74
Sell_money_20: 18.45
Sell_money_21: 9.18
Sell_stock_00: 0.00
Sell_stock_01: 0.00
Sell_stock_02: 0.00
Sell_stock_03: 0.00
Sell_stock_04: 0.00
Sell_stock_05: 0.00
Sell_stock_06: 0.00
Sell_stock_07: 0.00
Sell_stock_08: 0.00
Sell_stock_09: 3.13
Sell_stock_10: 0.00
Sell_stock_11: 0.00
Sell_stock_12: 2.76
Sell_stock_13: 1.38
Sell_stock_14: 0.69
Sell_stock_15: 0.35
Sell_stock_16: 0.17
Sell_stock_17: 0.09
Sell_stock_18: 0.04
Sell_stock_19: 0.02
Sell_stock_20: 0.01
Sell_stock_21: 0.01
```

| **Buy_money** | **Buy_stock** | **Sell_money** | **Sell_stock** | **SOC_money** | **SOC_stock** | **Price** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 10000 | 0 | 1587.65 |
| 5000 | 3.17479 | 0 | 0 | 5000 | 3.17479 | 1574.91 |
| 2500 | 1.56484 | 0 | 0 | 2500 | 4.73963 | 1597.6 |
| 1250 | 0.783203 | 0 | 0 | 1250 | 5.52284 | 1596.01 |
| 625 | 0.385921 | 0 | 0 | 625 | 5.90876 | 1619.5 |
| 312.5 | 0.187207 | 0 | 0 | 312.5 | 6.09596 | 1669.27 |
| 156.25 | 0.0923156 | 0 | 0 | 156.25 | 6.18828 | 1692.56 |
| 78.125 | 0.0445694 | 0 | 0 | 78.125 | 6.23285 | 1752.88 |
| 39.0625 | 0.022194 | 0 | 0 | 39.0625 | 6.25504 | 1760.05 |
| 0 | 0 | 5552.54 | 3.12752 | 5591.6 | 3.12752 | 1775.38 |
| 2795.8 | 1.60024 | 0 | 0 | 2795.8 | 4.72776 | 1747.11 |
| 1397.9 | 0.800212 | 0 | 0 | 1397.9 | 5.52798 | 1746.91 |
| 0 | 0 | 4844.4 | 2.76399 | 6242.3 | 2.76399 | 1752.69 |
| 0 | 0 | 2415.6 | 1.38199 | 8657.9 | 1.38199 | 1747.91 |
| 0 | 0 | 1232.7 | 0.690997 | 9890.6 | 0.690997 | 1783.94 |
| 0 | 0 | 592.55 | 0.345499 | 10483.1 | 0.345499 | 1715.06 |
| 0 | 0 | 298.648 | 0.172749 | 10781.8 | 0.172749 | 1728.8 |
| 0 | 0 | 149.015 | 0.0863746 | 10930.8 | 0.0863746 | 1725.21 |
| 0 | 0 | 74.5675 | 0.0431873 | 11005.4 | 0.0431873 | 1726.61 |
| 0 | 0 | 37.7437 | 0.0215937 | 11043.1 | 0.0215937 | 1747.91 |
| 0 | 0 | 18.4463 | 0.0107968 | 11061.6 | 0.0107968 | 1708.49 |
| 0 | 0 | 9.18122 | 0.00539841 | **11070.7** | 0.00539841 | 1700.73 |

## NOTES

### Define Variables with `upBound`

Whenever you're defining an optimization problem with PuLP, consider adding the parameter `upBound` to the variables you create as well.
Even if the variable's upper bounds are later on further restricted by your constraints, by setting a value for the `upBound` parameter,
you guarantee that your problem won't have problems related to unbounded variables.

### Set `cat` Parameter to Variables

Another good practice is to set the type of variable you're trying to create. By default, PuLP defines variables as continuous values.
The available `cat` values are:

- `pulp.LpInteger` or `"Integer"`: define integer variable.
- `pulp.LpContinuous` or `"Continuous"`: continuous variable.
- `pulp.LpBinary` or `"Binary"`: binary variables that can be set to either 0 or 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is extremely helpful! I have been a bit slow in my testing, now coming back to it!